# Mapforce generates oddities

Tags: xslt, xpath, map-force

I took over a project with files generated with Mapforce.
I read something like :

```
*[local-name()='no_regnat' and namespace-uri()=''][not((not((translate(string(@xsi:nil), 'true ', '1') = '1')) and (string(.) = '')))]
```

It seems it can be writen like this

```
no_regnat[not((boolean(@xsi:nil) and (string(.) = '')))]
```

Why is it doing the former ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us first consider the left side of the expressions,

```
*[local-name()='no_regnat' and namespace-uri()='']
```

and

```
no_regnat
```

In most contexts, they mean exactly the same, but in very specific situations, they do not yield the same result sequence:

If you define an `xpath-default-namespace` in your XSLT 2.0 stylesheet, the expressions do not deliver the same results:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xpath-default-namespace="www.no_regnat.com">

    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <results>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </results>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*[local-name()='no_regnat' and namespace-uri()='']">
       <!--Or: template match="no_regnat"-->
        <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Test the above with, for instance,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root xmlns:r="www.no_regnat.com">
    <no_regnat n="1"/>
    <r:no_regnat n="2"/>
    <other xmlns="www.no_regnat.com">
        <no_regnat n="3"/>
    </other>
</root>
```

And directly transform it online [here](http://xsltransform.net/pPqsHTC/1).

So, we would need to see the context of those expressions to decide whether Mapforce is indeed generating code that is too verbose.

---

Then, the second predicate:

```
translate(string(@nil), 'true ', '1')
```

is *really* odd, in my opinion. The `translate()` function only ever works with single characters, and that's why the strings that are the second and third argument of `translate()` usually have the same length. Characters in the second argument that do not have a counterpart in the third argument are translated to the empty string.

So, what the function is doing here is mapping `t` to `1`, and mapping `r`, `u` and `e` and  (whitespace) to nothing. `boolean()` is much more useful here.

---

But be careful with the semantics of those predicates:

```
[not((not((translate(string(@xsi:nil), 'true ', '1') = '1')) and (string(.) = '')))]
```

means

> do not allow cases where `xsi:nil` is `false` and the string value of the context element is empty

Whereas

```
[not((boolean(@xsi:nil) and (string(.) = '')))]
```

means

> do not allow cases where `xsi:nil` is `true` and the string value of the context element is empty

Most likely, the correct constraint is: if `xsi:nil = 'true'`, then the context element must be empty.